# The Set of All Vectors (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) whose Components Sum to 1 is Compact

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, compactness

In my lecture notes, my professor mentioned that the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose components are nonnegative and sum to $1$ is compact.

I am trying to prove this. Since the vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we just need to prove that the set is closed and bounded.

The set is closed is intuitive to me, but boundedness isn't.

Clearly, the vectors are bounded along every axis (choose one component to be $1$, and all other components to be $0$.) But that is only bouned in $n$ directions, how do I show that the set is bounded in all directions?

Comment: It is unbounded if $n > 1$. Think of $(x, 1-x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Seems to me like some misunderstanding. Maybe he referred to vector whose sum of squares of component sum to 1, or something like that?

Comment: You are right, I missed a condition!! I edited the question

Comment: Ok, if we only talk about nonnegative coordinates, then every coordinate is bounded between 0 and 1 and hence all the set is contained within the cube $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: Hint: every one of the components is no greater than $1$. That should produce an upper bound on the norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $f(x_1,\dots, x_n)=x_1+\dots+x_n$ is continuous, hence $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed (since $\{1\}$ is closed). Your set in question $S$ is $f^{-1}(\{1\})\bigcap_i \{x_i\geq 0\}  $ which is closed because is an intersection of closed sets.

It is also easy to see that $S$ is bounded in fact, $S\subset B(0,1)$. Since if $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in S$, we have $x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2\leq (x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)^2=1$.

You may think your set as a simplex (in 3D is a triangle with vertices at $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ )

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this set must be bounded, it remains to show that it is closed. Suppose that there is a cauchy sequence of elements of such set. Then then $\sum x^i_n$ is a convergent sequence and $\sum x^i_n \leq 1$ for all $n$. The limit $(x^1, \dots, x^m)$ is such that $\sum x^i\leq 1$.